# Display only leading spaces (and not tabs) in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, whitespace

I'm looking for an option (or combination of options) to have more granular control over the display of whitespace in IntelliJ IDEA.

I'm looking for options similar to Eclipse's:
[image: Eclipse whitespace configuration]

(General → Editors → Text Editors → Show whitespace characters → configure visibility)

More specifically, I only want to **see** leading spaces which conflict with the tab-only indentation in the code.

Note that I'm aware I can detect the leading spaces with a regex search and I can apply automatic formatting that fixes them - the point of the question is just to see the spaces (that's why I put it in bold above)

**Update:**

A similar issue was opened 2 years before my question on JetBrains tracker - it can be upvoted, if anyone is interested:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127020

Comment: Please check out this stackoverflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597544/show-only-trailing-whitespace-in-intellij-idea

Comment: @Mr.Noddy I was there, I even posted an answer myself :)

Comment: Ok... @Giovanni.... so finally you got the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such options in IntelliJ IDEA as of version 15.

Comment: Nor as of version 2018.1

Comment: Still no such option in 2019.1